# New Spring Cloud ServiceRegistry in Dalston

Tags: spring-cloud-consul

I was reviewing the new features in Dalston.  I was curious how to appropriately use the ServiceRegistry for Consul.

In both the register and deregister methods, it uses a ConsulRegistration object.  Where do I get this object to us in the deregister?

I checked DiscoveryClient and it seems to return ServiceInstance.

The scenario I am thinking of is to remove zombie services and I was to deregister an instance that I believe is bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can autowire ConsulRegistration object with Spring Boot.
The below test class might be helpful for you.

[Spring Cloud Consul: ConsulServiceRegistryTests](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-discovery/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/serviceregistry/ConsulServiceRegistryTests.java)